# What is wrong with this frameset code?

Tags: html, frames, frameset

I am using Webmin on my server. For some reason it's decided to stop displaying anything on the root page, it's completely blank. However it's still returning code, shown below. The individual pages in the frames work perfectly but the frameset just doesn't want to display, in any browser, for some reason.

I have stripped it right down to this, running on a local server but it still doesn't show anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<frameset cols="230,*">
    <frame name="left" src="test1.html" scrolling="auto">
    <frame name="right" src="test2.html" noresize>
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried removing and changing various attributes but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<frameset>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) element replaces the `<body>` element. You can't use both in the same document.

You should write:

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="230, *">
    <frame name="left" src="test1.html" scrolling="auto" />
    <frame name="right" src="test2.html" noresize="noresize" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `<body></body>` tag.